# javascript/dom -- how expensive is creating vs rearranging dom nodes?

Tags: javascript, optimization, dom

I'm trying to optimize a sortable table I've written. The bottleneck is in the dom manipulation. I'm currently creating new table rows and inserting them every time I sort the table. I'm wondering if I might be able to speed things up by simple rearranging the rows, not recreating the nodes. For this to make a significant difference, dom node rearranging would have to be a lot snappier than node creating. Is this the case?
thanks,
-Morgan

Comment: How many rows are there in the table you're sorting?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer as it will get downvoted for not answering your question, but have you seen the tablesort plugin for jQuery? - http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

Comment: yeah, it would have been smarter to use either that or data tables, but I went ahead and built my own before it occurred to me that this wheel had already been invented. May be just as well though, as I think I'm going to need to do a lot customization.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether creating or manipulating is faster, but I do know that it'll be faster if you manipulate the entire table when it's not on the page and then place it on all at once.  Along those lines, it'll probably be slower to re-arrange the existing rows in place unless the whole table is removed from the DOM first.

[This page](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31567&seqNum=5) suggests that it'd be fastest to clone the current table, manipulate it as you wish, then replace the table on the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

I'm drawing this table about twice as quickly now, using innerHTML, building the entire contents as a string, rather than inserting nodes one-by-by.

Comment: Instead of string = string + newstring, use an array: var a=[]; while(loop){ a.push(newstring) } result = a.join(""); // String concatenation in IE is terrible slow. I did a test once where Opera finished in about 4 seconds, and IE still hadn't finished after 20 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I came across that too, but with what I'm doing, it seems that it's still faster to add dom nodes than use innerHTML in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this page handy for some benchmarks:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this and decided to set up a quick benchmark http://jsfiddle.net/wheresrhys/2g6Dn/6/

It uses jQuery, so is not a pure benchmark, and it's probably skewed in other ways too. But the result it gives is that moving DOM nodes is about twice as fast as creating and detroying dom nodes every time

Answer (score 0):

if you can, it is better to do the dom manipulation not as actual dom manipulation, but as some sort of method within your script and then manipulating the dom.  So rather than doing what is called a repaint on every single node, you clump what would have been your repaint on every single node into its own method, and then attach those nodes into a parent that would then be attached to the actual dom, resulting in just two repaints instead of hundreds.  I say two b/c you need to cleanup what is in the dom already before updating with your new data.